# Python - class Flashcard - quizzing user in a loop

Tags: python, class, loops

I am trying to create a loop that quizzes the user with flashcards I have created.  When the user wants to exit, they should be able to type the letter 'q' and have the number of correct and incorrect answers print.  Here is what I have:

```
class Flashcard(object):
    def __init__(self, q, a) :
        self.question = q
        self.answer = a
    def print_question(self) :
        print self.question
    def quiz_user(self) :
        self.print_question()
        ans = raw_input("? ")
        correct = 0
        incorrect = 0
        if ans.strip().lower() == self.answer.strip().lower() and ans.strip().lower() != 'q':
            print "Good job!"
            correct = correct + 1
            return True
        elif ans.strip().lower() != self.answer.strip().lower() and ans.strip().lower() != 'q':
            print "Sorry, the answer was:", self.answer
            incorrect = incorrect + 1
            return False
        elif ans.strip().lower() == 'q':
            print "correct:", correct
            print "incorrect:", incorrect

import random

cards = [
    Flashcard("What is largest country in Africa?", "Algeria"),
    Flashcard("What is a group of larks called?", "exaltation")
    ]
while True :
    random.choice(cards).quiz_user()
```

When I run the code, I get an error saying that the "local variable 'incorrect' referenced before assignment".  How can I keep track of the correct and incorrect answers?  Should I be returning more than just True and False in quiz_user()? Would it help to make the quiz loop in a new class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you need to declare the two variables first, and then pass them in to and get them out each time, so try this:

```
correct = 0
incorrect = 0
cards = [
    Flashcard("What is largest country in Africa?", "Algeria"),
    Flashcard("What is a group of larks called?", "exaltation")
    ]
while True :
    result = random.choice(cards).quiz_user()
    if result: correct += 1
    elif not result: incorrect += 1
    else: break
```

That should allow you to keep using your True False structure, and have the code work. You could also then get rid of your references to correct and incorrect inside your class, and put the print statements in the while loop. Also change this:

```
elif ans.strip().lower() == 'q':
    print "correct:", correct
    print "incorrect:", incorrect
```

to this:

```
elif ans.strip().lower() == 'q': return None
```

to have the program stop when q is entered.

Comment: This worked after I switched around the correct and incorrect

Comment: Pretty good advice here. Do you have any ideas about how to make the program stop running when the user enters "q"? Right now it seems to loop forever.

Comment: Changes the answer to fix the correct and incorrect button issue, as well as add the functionality of ending the loop when q is entered. You will need to put both bits of code I changed in for it to work though.

Comment: Worked well except couldn't get the program to end when I entered q until I changed the "else: break" to "elif result == None: break"

Comment: Shouldn't have made a difference, but I'm glad it worked for you never the less.